# Form multiple choice options

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I've tried my best to try and figure this one out, and it might be quite basic for some, I've searched for solutions... I want this to be a straight forward fill out / email (I know how to do the email part) - unless it has to be database driven?

Basically, I've got a 10 question quiz, multiple choice A B C D - however A B C could be correct.

My html is (broke down)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="question1[]" id="question1" value="A" />
<label for="question1">A) Do you like this </label> 

<input type="checkbox" name="question1[]" id="question1" value="B" />
<label for="question1">A) Do you like this as well </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="question1[]" id="question1" value="C" />
<label for="question1">A) Do you like this as well well </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="question1[]" id="question1" value="D" />
<label for="question1">A) Do you like this as well well well </label>
```

So, this 'posts' through to another php file and I can work through the array to show which answer has been ticked-

```
    $myresults = $_POST['question1'];
    if(empty($myresults))
    {
    echo("You didn't answer in this section.");
    }
    else{
    $N = count($myresults);
    echo "<strong>Section 1:</strong> You selected $N answers: ";
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
    echo($myresults[$i] . " ");
    }
    }
```

So, sorry for waffling - basically, I just want to say A B C are correct - D is incorrect, add 1 to the score.

I think I need to create an 'if' statement something like this?

```
    if (($myresults == 'A') && ($myresults == 'B') && (myresults == 'C'))
    {
    echo "something might have worked!";
    $mycount++;
    }
```

I think I got quite close at some point today, but by the time I tried various fixes, I could'nt get back to where I was :(

But I am really unsure how to do this.

Many thanks for any help

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the answers together and check it that way.

```
sort($myresults);

$answers = implode($myresults);

if($answers == 'ABC'){
    echo 'Correct answers!';
    $mycount++;
}
```

Or you can check against your own array.

```
sort($myresults);

if($myresults == array('A','B','C')){
    echo 'Correct answers!';
    $mycount++;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero, I have been on this since 9 am (uk time) - I was so determined to try and solve it, but didn't. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Yeah!
Hi Andy
you may use in_array to ckeck if the options are in with this function ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php
Try use this function. Marcus Recck too write a great solution.

Have many functions to use like array_diff to extract options not selected.

Comment: Hi Fred, I tried in_array today, I just could'nt get my head around it, for some reason I suck at arrays, especially looping through them and retrieving results! thank you for your help also.